# How to deal with the URL in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my application I have a URL like this `/customers/details/1`. On this page there is a search box. What I want is, when a search is performed, the url must changed to `/customers/`.

This is what I've tried:

```
$location.path('/customers');

// call to service with search params and set the result to the customers list (asynchronous)
```

The result is that the URL is changed to `/customers` but the result of the search is not shown. When I perform the search again, I do get results.

My quess is that the first time, the query get's executed, but because I changed the path, the results are lost.

What I'd like to know is, what can I do, to change the URL and also show the search results in the 'new' URL?

Comment: Do you have a route defined for `/customers`?

Comment: Yes I have a route defined for `/customers`

Comment: How are the search parameters passed to search service or backend?

Comment: Your problem sounds like your doing some logic in a controller and so the data is lost between "views" you need to use a service to store your data and make your requests instead if this is the case.

Comment: @Chandermani When the user presses <enter> I call the `customerService` with the search keywords and the service make a call to the backend. I then a asynchronous response of the server.

Comment: @shaunhusain I as thinking the same thing. To create a searchDataStore or something to store my search keywords. But I am wondering if there're other options..

Comment: Basically your two options as far as I know are to use the angular .service since this creates a singleton or to use the .value method from angular which provides you a means of defining a variable value that lives outside of the controllers scope.  Anything made in the controllers scope will be eliminated when that controller is no longer needed (the view that uses it is removed).

Comment: Didn't know about the value method. Do you have link of that for more information?

Comment: Yup here's the link to the description in the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide I watched a YouTube video on it that tipped me off initially and describes it fairly well http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxuN6WO3tIA the second talk wasn't as good

Comment: Thanks. Can you post an answer and summarize your comments? That way I can accept that answer and give you the credits :)